# Error when trying to use react-keydown component

Tags: babeljs, reactjs, keydown

I am currently trying to use the react-keydown component as shown by the documentation on: [react-keydown component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keydown). My code looks as follows:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import keydown, { Keys } from 'react-keydown';

const propTypes = {
  onNewGame: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
  }

  @keydown( 'enter' )
  submit( event ) {
    console.log('clicked');
  }


render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="img-margin">
        <div className="margin">
          <img alt="" src="/assets/logo/logo_blank.png"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}}

Home.propTypes = propTypes;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Method has decorators, put the decorator plugin before the classes one.
```

I've installed babel-plugin-transform-decorators and included it in my .babelrc. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can I see your `.babelrc`?

Comment: `{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-decorators", "transform-object-rest-spread", "recharts"]
}`

Answer (score 0):

react-keydown has only been tested with transform-decorators-legacy. transform-decorators probably parses differently. Try removing that transform and see if it works then.

Answer (score -1):

You were looking at the wrong example I think. If you are using classes, you have to put the decorator outside the class. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keydown#for-classes-pass-keydown-events-into-your-component

```
//Move decorator above class
@keydown
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps( { keydown } ) {
    if ( keydown.event ) {
      // inspect the keydown event and decide what to do 
      console.log( keydown.event.which );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>keydown events will only get passed down after this DOM node mounts or is clicked on</div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```